# Java: Method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that checks grades and returns a pass etc. I get an error at the moment saying the method cannot be applied to given types. I'm not sure how arguments actually work. The error occurs inThank you for the main at if (!isValid()) and if (isPass()). help with my question

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

EDIT :

Thank you for the help with my question

Comment: Your methods are declared to take 1 argument each. And you aren't passing anything when you are calling them

Comment: You have your methods as accepting parameters, but you are trying to call them with no arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the methods as

```
public static boolean isValid(int grade) { /*...*/ }
public static boolean isPass(int grade) { /*...*/ }
```

Hence you will need to pass parameters to them when you invoke it :

```
if (!isValid(grade)) { /*...*/ }

if (isPass(grade)) { /*...*/ }
```